# Angular Inputs View Displays, Any way to Quickly Swap Test Input Data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular7

How do I create Mock data to plug in and test displays? Everytime, we want to view an HTML rendering, have to literally copy and paste data into Typescript file. Is there any toolset to conduct this?

Currently testing @Inputs, which are being displayed in HTML

In researching following options,

- It is not an API, so cannot use InMemoryDbService from “angular-in-memory-web-api”   https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-inmemory-web-api/
- Also not database, so cannot apply json-server   https://medium.com/letsboot/the-perfect-mock-backend-to-start-with-an-angular-application-3d751d16614f

What options exist to quickly swap Inputs? or do people have to copy and paste into each file, is this customary in Angular?

**Typescript**

```
export class CustomerView implements OnInit {

  @Input() customer: Customer;
    this.customer.name = "Joe";
    this.customer.address = "123 Maple STreet";
    this.customer.city = "Atlanta";
    this.customer.state = "GA";
    this.customer.zip= "30314";
    this.customer.phone = "555-444-77777";
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class = "row">
        <div> {{customer.name}} </div>
        <div> {{customer.address}} </div>
        <div> {{customer.city}} </div>
        <div> {{customer.state}} </div>
        <div> {{customer.zip}} </div>
        <div> {{customer.phone}} </div>
    </div>
```

[Display example plcture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pkkw.png)

Comment: You can create a service file and hard code the data values over there. Now you can fetch the data from there to different components.

Comment: hi @thisisyash, yeah that would reduce the steps, I just have to link the input to the service, additionally, have to import the directory file to the model, still some steps, but somewhat easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a json file or Object with the required fields.

```
  customerDummy = {
    name: "Joe",
    address: "123 Maple STreet",
    city: "Atlanta",
    state: "GA",
    zip: "30314",
    phone: "555-444-77777",
  }
```

Whenever you are you create a variable just assign the value. For eg

`@Input() customer: Customer = customerDummy;`